# Python global and local variable: How does the code work?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, global-variables, local-variables

I came across a code that allows users to enter a fruit name. Based on the input, it will be searched for from the basket list and show its quantity if the fruit is on the list.

If the fruit is not found, users can enter the quantity for that fruit and add it to the list.

```
basket = [
    {'fruit': 'apple', 'qty': 20},
    {'fruit': 'banana', 'qty': 30},
    {'fruit': 'orange', 'qty': 10}
]

fruit = input('Enter a fruit:')

index = 0
found_it = False

while index < len(basket):
    item = basket[index]
    # check the fruit name
    if item['fruit'] == fruit:
        found_it = True
        print(f"Basket has {item['qty']} {item['fruit']}(s)")
        break

    index += 1

if not found_it:
    qty = int(input(f'Enter the qty for {fruit}:'))
    basket.append({'fruit': fruit, 'qty': qty})
    print(basket)
```

But I don't understand the logic of the outer if condition. Which `found_it` is it referring to? The one defined before (global) the while statement or the one in it (local)? How does the outer `if` work?

Comment: There's no change in global/local scope happening here. The local `found_it` variable is being set to `False` initially, then is set to `True` if a match is found in the while loop. That way, when the loop is finished, it will only run the code at the end if the fruit wasn't found in the list.

Comment: Your code has just single variable for 'found_it' and your loop conditionally modifies the same. If statement is used to check if it was modified during the iteration of loop.

Comment: Oh, so the logic behind this is, if I key in "python", the while statement goes through the list until `index` >=`len(basket)` and renders the while condition `False`. It then exits the while loop without breaking. At this point, `found_it` is still `False` from the first assignment, as "python" cannot be found in the fruit basket and `found_it` is thus not modified in the while loop. Hence, outer if statement is executed since not `False` is `True`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but shows you how to sidestep the issue of using a mutable value at all to make decisions about what to do next.

---

Note that Python has a `while-else` construct that makes the `found_it` variable unnecessary.

```
basket = [
    {'fruit': 'apple', 'qty': 20},
    {'fruit': 'banana', 'qty': 30},
    {'fruit': 'orange', 'qty': 10}
]

fruit = input('Enter a fruit:')

index = 0

while index < len(basket):
    item = basket[index]
    # check the fruit name
    if item['fruit'] == fruit:
        print(f"Basket has {item['qty']} {item['fruit']}(s)")
        break

    index += 1
else:
    qty = int(input(f'Enter the qty for {fruit}:'))
    basket.append({'fruit': fruit, 'qty': qty})
    print(basket)
```

The `else` clause of the loop only executes if `break` wasn't used to exit the loop, i.e., when you would have changed the value of `found_it`.

---

Somewhat unrelated, you can iterate over the elements of `basket` directly, without bothering with an index.

```
basket = [
    {'fruit': 'apple', 'qty': 20},
    {'fruit': 'banana', 'qty': 30},
    {'fruit': 'orange', 'qty': 10}
]

fruit = input('Enter a fruit:')

for item in basket:
    # check the fruit name
    if item['fruit'] == fruit:
        print(f"Basket has {item['qty']} {item['fruit']}(s)")
        break
else:
    qty = int(input(f'Enter the qty for {fruit}:'))
    basket.append({'fruit': fruit, 'qty': qty})
    print(basket)
```

`else` behaves the same way with `for` as with `while`: it only executes if the loop exits "naturally", in this case by exhausting the iterator rather than when the loop condition becomes false.

Answer (score 0):

In python you don't explicitly declare a variable. It can be confusing but once variable exist in the scope, in this case global, then assigning to it will change its value and not create a new one. Best moments are when you misspell something, python will think you declared new variable with that value and original will not change. I don't really understand why creator of python introduced such ambiguity, fortunately new languages are avoiding this mistake.

Comment: Oh, but is it possible for both local and global variables to have the same name? If so, how does python distinguish them? For instance if I want to put a ```counter``` variable into a function or a loop I must first define it outside of the function/loop, otherwise there will be an error and ```counter``` will not be recognized. In this case, the ```counter``` outside and inside the function/loop are global and local variables (respectively) with the same names right?

Comment: Scopes are nested; names refer to the variable in the nearest containing scope. The `nonlocal` and `global` keywords are used for assigning to variables in a higher scope without creating a new variable in the current scope.

Comment: There is no way to refer to a variable in a higher scope if one of the same name exists in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

Running the code with a debugger shows that as soon as the first `found_it` is encountered,it is created both globally and locally so the `found_it` in the inner loop changes value that you declared initially.

[image: Debugger screenshot]

Regarding the working of the outer loop, `if not` is a condition that checks for truth i.e it will execute only if the value is false.

Using a regular `if-else` would be easier.